# Why do we have non-free software in the official repositories?

Tags: official-repositories, open-source

The [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) describes the "sections" of the official Ubuntu repositories as follows:

> Main - Officially supported software.
>
> Restricted - Supported software that
>   is not available under a completely
>   free license.
>
> Universe - Community maintained
>   software, i.e. not officially
>   supported software.
>
> Multiverse - Software that is not
>   free.

I thought that software in the Ubuntu repositories had to be open source, however doesn't the description of the *Multiverse* directly contradicts this?

Comment: There are different reasons, most of them subjective and argumentative.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The software in *Multiverse* is "[gratis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis)", but not free. These are some examples of cases in which software would be appropriate in Multiverse:

- The Software is [not legal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libdvdcss2) in every jurisdiction (DVD Decryption, ...)
- It's [software-patent encumbered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_patent) (MP3 Codecs, ...)
- It doesn't provide the user with **all of** the [four essential Freedoms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software#Definition):

  1. **Run** the program for any purpose.
  2. **Study** how the program works, and change it to make it do what you want.
  3. **Redistribute** copies at will.
  4. Modify the program, and **release modified versions**.

  Note that those do *not* include a requirement that modified version be released with a license that grants the same freedom. This is called [copyleft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft), and it's seperate from pure free software.
- There are issues with the licensing (like missing, unclear or invalid copyright notices)
- Any of the above is disputed or unclear

As htorque quotes, "The onus is on you to verify your rights to use this software ".

Note also: much of the software in Ubuntu enters the repositories through being in Debian first, so the [Debian Social Contract & The Debian Free Software Guidelines](http://www.debian.org/social_contract) are of some relevance.

Comment: Great info, but as far as I can see this doesn't answer the question. It talks about what is the situation, but not why. I believe that you can expand a little bit the answer with that info.

Comment: very good point. But I'm very hesitant to explain why, because there isn't really a well documented, factual answer. It's going to be subjective. I don't want to get into a holy-war argument. But I'll think about it, and see if I can't find a few documented reasons. Maybe @MarkShuttleworth should answer the question. (he is [around](http://askubuntu.com/users/5287/mark-shuttleworth)) ;-)

Answer (score 9):

I'm not Shuttleworth, but the Ubuntu objective is not to ship a *Pure Free Distro*, but to solve [Bug number 1](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1). In order to be able to solve it, it needs to supply non-free software that users demands. Specially closed software firmware that is needed by lots of drivers to work.

If you are interested in a totally free system you can select "Only install free software" while installing Ubuntu.

Summarizing the answer in just one word: **Pragmatism**.

Comment: Gobuntu is no more; it's been merged into mainline Ubuntu, you can now get the same effect by selecting "Only install free software" on the Live CD boot-screen.

Answer (score -2):

My answer is no

Now we should make it clear first as to what "free" means here. Are you talking about free of charge or free of use?

I believe open source concept is free of use, but it doesn't necessarily have to be free of charge as well.

Comment: That's not what he meant. There is non-free software in main because it's necessary in order for people to use Ubuntu. Drivers, etc.