# What is the objective of Ubuntu?

Tags: canonical, multiverse, free-software

When I visited [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/25774/272474) post I am surprised about the objective of Ubuntu! As it says:

> I'm not Shuttleworth, but the Ubuntu objective is **not** to ship a Pure Free Distro, but to solve [Bug number 1](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1).

But the [Phiosophy](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/our-philosophy) page says:

> Ubuntu software is free. Always was, always will be.

However, from the Q/A I mentioned as well as Ubuntu's multiverse is *full of* non-free software at considerably large, I'm confused Whether Ubuntu recommends freedom or not? as it sounds freedom is ***not*** the goal.

I want to know the real fact : **What is the objective of Ubuntu?**

<sup>By the way,, <s>Which</s>/What is Bug Number 1? Why "[Microsoft has a majority market share](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1)" is at **No-1**?</sup>

Comment: Yes, that was bug #1, now closed. Note the "free" that that user talks about is not monetary value, but software freedom. There are pure free distros like Trisquel or gNewSense. Ubuntu includes "non-free" software like binary-blob software drivers from NVidia, AMD, etc., and stuff like Flash.

Comment: @muru I  knew correct meaning of free (as in freedom); [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre#.22Free_beer.22_vs_.22free_speech.22_distinction) is good explanation

Comment: I can't understand how this is not being closed for being too broad. Will flag again once bounty it's over. I've seen much higher quality questions being closed.

Answer (score 5):

To know Objective of Ubuntu read the bug no 1 description, and you'll get it all.

These are Objectives of Ubuntu: [Quoted from Bug#1 Description](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1)

- Our work is driven by a belief that software should be free and
  accessible to all.
- "Ubuntu software is free. Always was, always will be.
- Free software gives everyone the freedom to use it however they want and share with whoever they like.
- At the other, we are able to give access to essential software for those who couldn’t otherwise afford it
- Non-free software leaves users at the mercy of the software owner and concentrates control over the technology which powers our society into the hands of a few. Additionally, proprietary software stifles innovation, maintains artificial scarcities, and enables malicious anti-features such as DRM, surveillance, and other monopolistic practices.

I can't think there is any techni or humanity manner greate than those, the above points in easily simple words and work is just saying We(company,community and users) are ready to provide Freedom in Computing world.